# How to manipulate HTML elements using jquery?

Tags: jquery, html, database, dom

I have this table which loads from a database, so all elements from `each row` have same attributes.

```
<table class="table table-responsive">
    <tr>
        <th>Product name</th>
        <th>Quantity</th>
        <th>Price per unit</th>
        <th>Total</th>
        <th>Action</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td class="product-name">Product one name</td>
        <td class="product-quantity">
            <!-- plus button should increase quantity and update total based on unit_price*quantity  -->
            <button class="btn"> +</button>
            <input type="text" value="2"/>
            <button class="btn"> -</button>
        </td>
        <td class="unit-price">50</td>
        <td class="total-price">100</td>
        <td>
            <!-- this should delete entire row -->
            <button class="product-delete">Delete</button>
        </td>
    </tr>
    ...
</table>
<!-- on each quantity change this needs to update -->
<div class="grand-total"> 5000 </div>
```

I tried to make `jQuery` but couldn't work it out since every row has same attributes I am unable to select specific row and update it's contents to make this work.

I searched a lot, but all I found is HTML manipulation based on id and class selector which I can't use since elements from each row have same class and I can't give unique id to every element because they load from database(PHP).

I would really appreciate if anyone could tell me how to do this in `jQuery`. And please do not give me links to static `HTML` manipulation using `jQuery` I want a solution for dynamic `HTML elements`.

Comment: what type of operation you have to perform on table

Comment: @Aniket Deshmukh What you need is some **unique id** or **unique data** for every row/product in your database table if you don't have that then it is not possible to **`delete/update`** particular row in database.

Comment: I have unique ID for every product but I could give it to product name  <td class="product-name" id="product_id"> what now?

Comment: @AniketDeshmukh i have added answer for it please have a look on it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Updated: Here is the working example: [Fiddle example](https://jsfiddle.net/ra3cr7s7/5/)
and the code is:

```
$('.btn, .product-delete').on("click", function(){

 $this=$(this);
var unitPrice=parseInt($this.parents("tr").find(".unit-price").text());

  switch($this.text()){
    case " +": 
       currentVal=       parseInt($this.parents("tr").find("input[type='text']").val());
    newVal=currentVal+1;
    $this.parents("tr").find("input[type='text']").val(newVal); 

    $this.parents("tr").find(".total-price").text(unitPrice*newVal);  

      break;

    case " -": 
      currentVal=  parseInt($this.parents("tr").find("input[type='text']").val());

      if(currentVal==0){
        break;
      }

    newVal=currentVal-1;
    $this.parents("tr").find("input[type='text']").val(newVal); 

    $this.parents("tr").find(".total-price").text(unitPrice*newVal);

      break;

    case "Delete":
      $this.parents("tr").remove();

  }

  //sum all total cols
   var total=0;
  $(".total-price").each(function(){
   total+= parseInt($(this).text());

  });

 $(".grand-total").text("Total "+total);

});
```

Comment: Updated, with multiple rows

Comment: Thanks I think your answer is optimal than one I worked out

Answer (score 1):

Hi i have added working demo code which help you lot.

i have added a click event on button and in event w.r to the button i have search for parent tr of element and from parent tr i can find every thing inside that tr with jquery method.

see the code and understand it defiantly it will help you

```js
$(document).ready(function(e) {
  $(document).on("click", ".addContity", function(e) {
    var parentTR = $(this).closest("tr");
    console.log(parentTR);
    console.log($(parentTR).find(".quantityText"));
    var quantityText = parseInt($(parentTR).find(".quantityText").val());
    $(parentTR).find(".quantityText").val(quantityText + 1);
  });
  $(document).on("click", ".removeQuatity", function(e) {
    var parentTR = $(this).closest("tr");
    console.log(parentTR);
    var quantityText = parseInt($(parentTR).find(".quantityText").val());
    if (quantityText > 0) {
      $(parentTR).find(".quantityText").val(quantityText - 1);
    }

  });

  $(document).on("click", ".btnDelete", function(e) {

    alert("button delete logic will go here.");
  });


});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table class="table table-responsive">
  <tr>
    <th>Product name</th>
    <th>Quantity</th>
    <th>Price per unit</th>
    <th>Total</th>
    <th>Action</th>
  </tr>

  <tr>
    <td class="product-name">Product one name</td>
    <td class="product-quantity">
      <button class="btn addContity">+</button>
      <input type="text " class="quantityText" value="2" />
      <button class="btn removeQuatity">-</button>
    </td>
    <td class="unit-price">50</td>
    <td class="total-price">100</td>
    <td>
      <button class="product-delete btnDelete">Delete</button>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>

<div class="grand-total">5000</div>
```

Comment: Awesome!! works perfect, I have been looking for this for a week. Just one  more question though how do I get text in <div class="grand-total">5000</div>, I used input text type for showing total price and used your logic to update total-price, but i don't want to use input text type for last grand total

Comment: using jqeury using classname of div or provoide id to that div so as to it should be uniuqe.

Using class selector. $(".grand-total").empty().append("total ammount from claculation");

or bu sing id $("#idofgrand-total").empty().append("total ammount from claculation");

Answer (score 1):

Hi i have added demo code which help you. and for each new td you need to input type which contain product id and its name and it should be hidden. By taking product id and name you can update and delete the same product.

Note : if you are accessing data form database you will get product id and its name and you can pass these values to input tag as mention above respectively.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
   $('#AddButton').click( function() {
   var counter = $('#TextBox').val();
   counter++ ;
   $('#TextBox').val(counter);
   });
   $('#removButton').click( function() {
   var counter = $('#TextBox').val();
   counter-- ;
   $('#TextBox').val(counter);
   });

   $('#productDel').click( function() {
   var counter = $('#TextBox').val();
   counter-- ;
   $('#TextBox').val(counter);
   });
  
  $(document).on("click", ".productDel", function(e) {
    alert("Are You sure want to delete product Name");
  });
  
  
  $( "#AddButton" ).click(function() {
    var produnitPric = parseInt($( "td.unit-price" ).html());
    var prodtotalPric = parseInt($( "td.total-price" ).html());
    var priceperunit = produnitPric + 50;
    var totalPrice = prodtotalPric + 30;
    alert("Total Price :" + totalPrice);
    alert("Total Price Per Unit :" + priceperunit);
  });


});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <title>Select</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <script type='text/javascript' src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

</head>


<body>

<div class="box current" style="background: red"></div>
<div class="box" style="background: blue"></div>


<table class="table table-responsive">
    <thead>
      <th>Product name</th>
      <th>Quantity</th>
      <th>Price per unit</th>
      <th>Total</th>
      <th>Action</th>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr class="success">
 <input type="hidden" name="ProductName" value="productID">
       <td class="product-name">Product one name</td>

       <td class="product-quantity"><input type="Button" class="btn btn-danger btn-xs" id='removButton' value="-" /> <input type="text" name="TextBox" id="TextBox" value="5" 

/> <input type="Button" id='AddButton' value="+" class="btn btn-success btn-xs" /> </td>
     <td class="unit-price">50</td>
     <td class="total-price">100</td>
     <td><button class="productUpdate btn btn-success btn-xs">Update</button> <button class="productDel btn btn-danger btn-xs">Delete</button></td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You have used ID as selector, won't it select every button in every row with same id? I mean every row will have a button with id='Addbutton'. I think id should be unique in html?

Comment: Yes in every new tr you will have input type hidden by keeping that hidden value or product id you need to implement. and also you can use this code on add and remove button and it only points to that particular tr.
var TextBox = parseInt($(parentTR).find(".TextBox").val());
$(parentTR).find(".TextBox").val(TextBox + 1);

Answer (score 0):

why not use use class-based jQuery selection? are you meaning to change attribtues of only a number of elements, and not the whole class?

If you decide you cannot use class based jQuery selection, you could resort to changing classes with jQuery, which is very easy:

```
$(".product-name").toArray().forEach(function(product){ 
  if (product.innerText == "name1")
    // product.className = "some other class"
});
```

Comment: Your answer does not attempt to answer the question. It should possibly be an edit, a comment, another question, or deleted altogether.

Comment: That's the problem if I use class selection every row will be selected and I want to select only one row where operation is performed with plus minus and delete buttons.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the final solution I worked out from Rahul's answer.

```js
$(document).ready(function(e) {
  var total = 0;
            $('.totalPriceText').each(function(){
                total += parseInt($(this).text());
                $(".grand-total").text(total);
            });

            $(document).on("click", ".addContity", function (e) {
                var parentTR = $(this).closest("tr");

                var quantityText = parseInt($(parentTR).find(".quantityText").val());
                var priceText = parseInt($(parentTR).find(".priceText").text());
                var totalPriceText = parseInt($(parentTR).find(".totalPriceText").text());

                $(parentTR).find(".quantityText").val(quantityText + 1);

                $(parentTR).find(".totalPriceText").text((quantityText + 1) * priceText);

                var total = 0;
                $('.totalPriceText').each(function(){
                    total += parseInt($(this).text());
                    $(".grand-total").text(total);
                });
            });


            $(document).on("click", ".removeQuatity", function (e) {
                var parentTR = $(this).closest("tr");

                var quantityText = parseInt($(parentTR).find(".quantityText").val());
                var priceText = parseInt($(parentTR).find(".priceText").text());
                var totalPriceText = parseInt($(parentTR).find(".totalPriceText").text());

                if (quantityText > 1) {
                    $(parentTR).find(".quantityText").val(quantityText - 1);
                    $(parentTR).find(".totalPriceText").text((quantityText - 1) * priceText);

                    var total = 0;
                    $('.totalPriceText').each(function(){
                        total += parseInt($(this).text());
                        $(".grand-total").text(total);
                    });
                }
            });

            $(document).on("click", ".btnDelete", function (e) {
                var parentTR = $(this).closest("tr");
                $(parentTR).remove();

                var total = 0;
                $('.totalPriceText').each(function(){
                    total += parseInt($(this).text());
                    $(".grand-total").text(total);
                });
            });


});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table class="table table-responsive">
  <tr>
    <th>Product name</th>
    <th>Quantity</th>
    <th>Price per unit</th>
    <th>Total</th>
    <th>Action</th>
  </tr>

  <tr>
    <td class="product-name">Product one name</td>
    <td class="product-quantity">
      <button class="btn addContity">+</button>
      <input type="text " class="quantityText" value="1" />
      <button class="btn removeQuatity">-</button>
    </td>
    <td class="unit-price priceText">100</td>
    <td class="total-price totalPriceText">100</td>
    <td><button class="product-delete btnDelete">Remove</button></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="product-name">Product two name</td>
    <td class="product-quantity">
      <button class="btn addContity">+</button>
      <input type="text " class="quantityText" value="1" />
      <button class="btn removeQuatity">-</button>
    </td>
    <td class="unit-price priceText">200</td>
    <td class="total-price totalPriceText">200</td>
    <td><button class="product-delete btnDelete">Remove</button></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="product-name">Product three name</td>
    <td class="product-quantity">
      <button class="btn addContity">+</button>
      <input type="text " class="quantityText" value="1" />
      <button class="btn removeQuatity">-</button>
    </td>
    <td class="unit-price priceText">50</td>
    <td class="total-price totalPriceText">50</td>
    <td><button class="product-delete btnDelete">Remove</button></td>
  </tr>
</table>

Grand Total<div class="grand-total">0</div>
```